# How to manage stack navigation based on app module?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new in React Native and I want to create stack navigation based on modules like

Auth

- Login
- Register
- Forgot
- Home

Home

- Dashboard
- Tabs
- Profile

1 - Auth stack have only above routes access where user can only navigate
2 - Home stack have only above routes access where user can navigate around home stack

Please guide here or any sample existing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained with examples in react navigation [authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) guide.

Here's simple example based on your routes -

```js
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabsScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Forgot" component={ForgotScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  </>
);
```

Comment: thank you @vinayr for your feedback, can I get more code information or any GitHub public repo so I can understand well.

Comment: @BhavinParghi you can see full example here https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/example/src/Screens/AuthFlow.tsx